# Triggering side-effects outside the ngrx store via component output

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, side-effects

I have a module with a modal in which I do some form work, the modal has it's tiny feature store.

When I finish my work (trigger: a successful save), I need to fire an output event, so that my context (the component that wraps my modal) can close the modal. I cannot go via a classic action - the context is not aware of my actions, and can only respond to an Output on my component.

So what I have is now this:

```
@Component MyComponent {
  @Output() closeModal = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private store: Store<MyState>, private actions: Actions) {
    // Here I subscribe to actions. Is there another way to do this?
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(actionTypes.SaveSuccess),
      tap(() => this.closeModal.emit(),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? importing actions stream to a component seems wrong, and I would like to avoid having to add new keys to my state interface just for this.

Edit: To clarify, I want to fire an Output event on my Component based on some ngrx action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening to the actions stream within a component does have a use-case. It might feel weird at the beginning, but I don't see nothing wrong it. We're also going to add an example of this in the ngrx.io docs - see the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2236).

In the future you could use [`@ngrx/component`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2187) for it.

I use @ngrx/effects  to handle dialog flows, but I'm not sure if it fits your use case. See [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#2-handling-the-flow-of-a-angular-material-dialog) for an example and more info on how to do it.

Comment: I agree with Tim. I do exactly that in some of my apps - listen to the actionsSubject inside the modal component and on success action fire the output event. I actually kind of like this pattern..

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for - basically just to confirm that while what I'm doing is atypical, it is not _wrong_.